# jquery lightbox does not load images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to get [this lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) to work and I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>            
    <!-- Lightbox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {        
            $("img.comidas").lightBox();
        });

    </script>       
</head>
```

The images are displyed in this manner:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="images/big-boss-adulto.jpg"><img src="images/big-boss-adulto.jpg" width="118" height="170" class="comidas"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/big-boss-cachorro.jpg" width="118" height="170" class="comidas"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/eukanuba-adulto.jpg" width="118" height="170" class="comidas"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

(I'm only trying if the lightbox works on the first image)

The problem id the following, the lightbox gets stuck here (in the loading part):

[image]

Things I've checked and that I can infer:

- All the js and css are correctly linked and exist
- The javascript and styleshit of the lightbox are probable working correctly since:

  - The style seems to be the correct
  - When you click outside the image (or press esc) the lighbox disappears

Another thing I've checked was using load:

```
$(window).load(function() {       
    $("img.comidas").lightBox();
});
```

But the same problem seems to persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try selecting the containing `<a>` element, instead of the image itself, for the `lightbox()` function.

Answer (score 4):

You are targeting the wrong element in your JS. You need to target the anchor link around the image, rather than the image itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I accepted Aaron's answer only because it came some seconds before, you have my +1 all the same! :)

Comment: @tw16 Since we basically answered at the same time, it's only fair that I give you an upvote to offset the difference.