# Lightbox doesnt load images. Stuck at loading part

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, lightbox, lightbox2

First of all, i'm kinda beginnner.

I've got similar problem to this:
[jquery lightbox does not load images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515296/jquery-lightbox-does-not-load-images)

Lightbox working, but somehow it cannot load the image (on the server).

[image: loading]

I need second pair of eyes on it:

head part:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
  <title>...</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
     @import "something.css";
  </style>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

somewhere in the body:

```
<a href="images/photo.jpg" data-lightbox="3" title="title"><img class="HoverBorder" alt="something" src="images/photo2.jpg" id="rightImg" /></a>
```

This works when I'm launching website from my drive. When I'm loading to my server it stucks at loading parts.
I tried to switch body part to direct links on my server, but also doesnt work.

Do You guys need something more?

Comment: You want me to paste everything?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UFtqK/

Same code but ok, here You are.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem after like a week of googling the h*ll out of it.

My problem was identical to yours - when running on my HDD, lightbox loaded images without any problem, but when I uploaded the web to the server and tried to load the image in lightbox from there, I got stuck with the loading animation.

I tried literally every possible solution I found on the internet, but nothing worked. So I sucked it up and started working on another problem involving image loading failure (background image linked via css file) and found out, that **the server I use sees a difference between *.jpg and *.JPG, which is a thing my computer does not do.**

So, if your file paths are all right, try to play with your files' suffixes. That could help you.

Hope you solve this annoying bug soon.
Take care and good luck.